# How to deal with automatically generated values in strongly types languages when defining a generic CRUD?

Tags: scala, haskell, crud, generic-programming

So I imagine that a generic CRUD has all basic operations on some type. Insert, read, delete, etc.
Yet how do I define an "insert" operation on such generic type if the crud internally will generate some of the values?

```
trait GenericCrud[E]{
    def insert(value:E): Unit // but in the insert I really don't want to provide a value E, but some incomplete version of it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Normally you can use a typeclass in a tagless way, where

   ```hs
   class (MonadIO mio) => Crud a mio where
     read :: ? -> mio a
   ```

   Personally I do not like it
2. But I would recommend you use Free Monad that

   ```hs
   data Crud c a where
     Read :: c -> Crud c a
     Insert :: c -> a -> Crud c a
     Create :: a -> Crud c a
     Delete :: c -> Crud c a
     deriving Functor
   ```

   Then intercept the algebra to `IO`.

Comment: What does "c" represent in your example?

Comment: If you like to use `StateT IO`, then you can just remove `c`.  But if you want to put some infomation as bifunctor, perhaps putting `c` here is useful.

Comment: For example, you may like to put entity id into process.  And intercept `Curd Id a` as `IO (Id,a)`, which gives the new entity id of the Create operation.

Comment: My mistake, I shall put c in Delete and Insert.

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question. I'm not that knowledgeable about Haskell, but regardless of that, my question is about how to represent typesafely that the CRUD service implemented will provide certain values on creation (such as creation timestamp and/or id)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  Do you mean something like servant (for RESTful) or like bean (for database)?  Servant: https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html. Beam: https://tathougies.github.io/beam/